# too many redirects in directory aside drupal

Tags: .htaccess

I installed drupal in a webroot where there were 4 directories:
_database
_demos
_test
_old

[image]

When I try to access to some of those directories there is a message:
"ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS"

My drupal htaccess is the default of Drupal 7.38 and using clean urls. Those directories doesnt have any index.html

Comment: what do you mean by 'join to some of those directories' ?

Comment: http://www.domain.com/_database/    ...by example. Using a browser.

Comment: your question is still lacking a great deal of information - are you saying you installed Drupal in a folder with existing sub-folders (horrible idea), and that when you try to access (join) those non-Drupal folders you get an error?

Comment: Yes, that is correct

Comment: Then your question appears to be off topic as it relates to existing conditions prior to a Drupal installation

Comment: No, because this error does not exist without drupal.

Comment: the problem is not caused by Drupal, it is caused by bad planning - by design, htaccess that ships with Drupal restricts access to a great deal, and forces most calls to the index.php file for security and other reasons.  Even if a solution exists via HTACCESS manipulation, that is off topic because htaccess is not specific to only Drupal - the problem could easily be reproduced without Drupal being installed